# Symmetries of Classical Electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, symmetry, resource-recommendations

I'm looking for a concise text where classical electrodynamics' symmetries are enlisted, proven and explained.

So far I´ve found different texts with just some of them and vaguely, or extensively, explained. I'm looking only for a review on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solid review on topics concerning symmetries in classical electrodynamics can be found in Scheck's book on [Classical Field Theory](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-55579-8), specifically the following chapters -

2. [Symmetries and Covariance of the Maxwell Equations](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-55579-8_2) and
3. [Maxwell Theory as a Classical Field Theory](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-55579-8_3).

To fully grasp the contents in these chapters, one is expected to have a working understanding of differential geometry to the degree of the exposition in Scheck's previous book on [Mechanics](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-55490-6).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes! This helped a lot. Thank you so much.